# Percentage lost

Tags: functions, percentages

I need a formula to calculate something like this

if I have 5000 dollars and loose 5% of it per DAY. 
How many days is it going to take to have 10 dollars left in my pockets.

Comment: Losing 5% is the same as saying you only have 95% of it left. So after three days you'll have 95% of 95% of 95% of 5000 which is $.95^3\times5000$

Comment: Yeah that works, but it's not the formula I was looking for. However that will work. Thanks

Comment: $5000(1+0.05)^n=10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - starting out with $\$X$, if you lose $x\%$ everyday, then after $1$ day, you'll have $(100-x)\%$. So, after $n$ days, if you have $Y$ dollars, then you'll have to solve:
$$Y=\left(1-\dfrac{x}{100}\right)^nX$$
In this case, you have [$n\approx121.158$ days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+5000%2a%280.95%29%5En%3D10).

Answer (score 2):

- Day 1: $5000$
- Day 2: $5000 - 0.05 \times 5000 = 5000 \times 0.95 = 4750$
- Day 3: $4750 - 0.05 \times 4750 = 4750 \times 0.95 = 5000 \times 0.95 \times 0.95 = 5000 \times 0.95^2$
- $\ldots$
- Day n: $5000 \times 0.95^n$

Now, solve:

$$5000 \times 0.95^n = 10 \implies n = 121.158$$

Comment: Beat me by $10$ seconds! :-)